# How to call zoho invoice rest api after access and refresh token?

Tags: oauth, token, access-token, refresh-token, zoho

I am following the steps mentioned in
https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/oauth/#overview
able to get access token and refresh token.

and not clear what to pass for invoice rest API for example
How to get the list of invoices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoho's documentation has an example call to list invoices :
https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/invoices/#list-invoices

```
curl https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices
-H "X-com-zoho-invoice-organizationid: 10234695"
-H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken 1000.41d9f2cfbd1b7a8f9e314b7aff7bc2d1.8fcc9810810a216793f385b9dd6e125f"
```

So it looks like you will need to pass 2 items of information to get a list of invoices:

1. Your zoho-invoice-organizationid
2. Your access token

Here is a pseudo-code example with the 2 items in curly-brackets

```
curl https://invoice.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices
-H "X-com-zoho-invoice-organizationid: {my-zoho-invoice-organizationid}"
-H "Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken {my-access-token}"
```

Comment: Thankyou very much ZohoCoder for the immediate response. 
I am able to connect and get the list of invoices.  for 
-H Authorization: , I was passing only access token. That caused the error at my side  and it worked after prerefixing string"Zoho-oauthtoken" with access_token. Yes. its there on the step 6.
https://www.zoho.com/invoice/api/v3/oauth/#overview